# android layout_weight squeezing an view too thin

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't seem to figure out how to effectively use android's layout_weight attribute. I'm trying to create a custom listView that has three textView's. The primary textView resides at the top left, then i have a text view that resides in the top right for, and then the third one that lives underneath the primary textView. I'd like the primary and the top right two be on the some horizontal axis but i want the primary textView to take up about 70% of the width, while the other textView takes the remaining 30%. No matter what weight i assign to the primary and right textView, the primary textView is always larger and squeezes the right data textView wayyy too thin.

[image]

My code:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="5dip"
              android:id="@+id/Llayout">
<!-- Title-->
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/primaryTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading some tadglkj dgjg sadlgkj dgksgj sgj sdgk"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:background="#888"
        android:layout_weight="4"/>

<!-- Right Data -->
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textColor="#B53021"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#bada55"
        android:text="1.3 mi"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Secondary title -->
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondaryTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:text="hello this is some other data"/>
```

Comment: You have to add Weightsum on its parent, in this case the linearlayout.

Comment: ok, i added a weighsum of 10 to the parent and then made the layout_weight's of the both views to 5 expecting the widths to be the same. The primary textView was still way bigger than 50%

Comment: If you want the widths to be the same, just add android:layout_weight="1" to both element (and don't put the weightSum attribute in your container)

Comment: You need to set the layout_width to fill_parent or 0dp for the textviews.

Comment: you need to set the layout width to 0dp after you set the weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do a couple things.

1. Assign a weightSum to my LinearLayout that housed the TextViews
2. I then needed to change the layout_width of the TextViews to "0dp" instead of "wrap_content"

   ```
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:id="@+id/Llayout"
                 android:weightSum="10">

       <!-- Title-->
       <TextView
               android:id="@+id/primaryTitle"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Loading..."
               android:textColor="#040404"
               android:typeface="sans"
               android:textSize="18dip"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:paddingTop="0dp"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="8"/>

       <!-- Right Data -->
       <TextView
               android:id="@+id/rightData"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="2"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
               android:textSize="12dip"
               android:textColor="#B53021"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:text="..."/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <!-- Secondary title -->
   <TextView
           android:id="@+id/secondaryTitle"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textColor="#343434"
           android:textSize="12dip"
           android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
           android:text="..."/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

On the item that you want to be 70% set the `layout_weight="30"` and on the item you want to be 30% set the `layout_weight="70"`. That should hopefully solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need you need to define a weight sum in your container.  In your case, this would look something like this (only including the relevant attributes you need):

```
<LinearLayout 
      android:weightSum="1">
<!-- Title-->
<TextView
     android:layout_weight=".7"/>

<!-- Right Data -->
<TextView
       android:layout_weight=".3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you mean to put layout_weight for the right data textview?

Comment: Yeah, I was just answering in general terms, this is the proper way to use Weight sums.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="0dp" in both the TextViews

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

The android:weightSum is not needed.